Why is Wildfly 26 suddenly causing Spring to identify injectable components?
I'm investigating migrating a large codebase from deploying on Wildfly 23.0.1 to 26.1.3.
One of the JARs being deployed within the EAR uses Spring, and provides an entrypoint to an otherwise-exclusively-EE/EJB CDI landscape:
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class MyFooComponentFactory {
  @Bean
  public MyFooComponent() {
    return new JndiTemplate()
        .lookup(name(MyFooComponent.class), MyFooComponent.class);
    }
}

The implementation of the MyFooComponent interface uses EJB annotations at field level, e.g.:
@Resource
private SessionContext ctx;

@EJB
private OtherComponent other;

When running in Wildfly 23, the server starts without any issues. But when I try to deploy to Wildfly 26, Spring throws a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for OtherComponent.
This is because, on Wildfly 23, Spring creates an org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata with empty collections for the injectedElements and checkedElements fields.
But for Wildfly 26, these fields are non-empty, meaning Spring tries to inject them. But they aren't defined in the Spring application context, because it's already being handled by EJB.
UPDATE
I've now identified that the reason InjectionMetadata is constructed differently on versions 23 and 26 is because org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#buildResourceMetadata is navigating up the class hierarchy for MyFooComponent (actually it's MyFooComponent$$$view530, which I assume is a JBoss proxy?)
For Wildfly 23, clazz.getSuperclass() returns java.lang.Object, but for Wildfly 26, it returns the MyFooComponentImpl class, and then that returns java.lang.Object.
The fields on the -Impl are responsible for the non-empty metadata.
So, can anyone tell me why this happens? Classloader changes between Wildfly 23 and 26?

I don't know what has changed, but it's likely not a class loading issue. There were nearly 2,200 changes between those releases :) https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/compare/23.0.2.Final...26.1.3.Final.
